# loading .php file into textbox using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi there good day to you Maam/Sir.
I have a problem with my textbox field which is that I can't load the file in the textbox but I can load it in div

I have this code bellow

```
 $(document).ready(function(e){
     $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
     setInterval(function(){$('#name').load('name.php');}, 1500);
    });

<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
```

I can't determine what is the problem there. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: it's an input field. you can't `.load()` those. you **CAN** set its `.val()`, however. load() sucks in some html and inserts it into the dom at the specified point. an input is a terminal node. it cannot contain ANY "sub" html.

Comment: is there any way to load the .php file?
and yes I tried .val and it worked but I want to load the file into textbox

Comment: "and it worked but" Huh? if it worked, then what's the problem?

Comment: I need to load the .php file every 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `.load()` loads data from the server and inserts the returned HTML into an element.  An `<input />` element is *not* one you can insert HTML into; instead you will need to give it a value by adjusting it's `value` attribute.

Try something like this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('name.php', function (data) {
            $('#name').val(data);
        });
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: I just created a test [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kt1q57fk/) and it worked.  Forgive the request to `/robots.txt`, it was the first simple thing I could find on that same domain

Answer (score -1):

It is because the .load() function inserts the data into the HTML brackets, not as a input value.  You have to set it's value.

```
$("#name").val("xxx");
```

Comment: but I need to load the file. Is there any way to load the file to the textbox sir?

Comment: What is the PHP file returning?  .load() is used for getting HTML content from PHP, it's not for what you are trying to do. If it's just a value, use AJAX and .get() to put the value from PHP into the textbox value.